# Gas fireplace - no spark for igniter - Martin DV5500 RVN

Tags: gas, fireplace

My home is 15 years old and has a gas fireplace (Martin Industries DV5500 RVN). When I press the plunger for the igniter, no spark is produced. I do not see any tears or cuts in the wire from the igniter to the pilot light. Also, when I hold the igniter in my hand I can feel a shock.

I cannot seem to find a way to remove the glass. I think mine is sealed. If that's the case, how would I clean the assembly inside the fireplace or diagnose issues if I cannot get inside? What other steps can I take to try to get this to work?

[image: Fireplace]

[image: Product label]

[image: Gas valves]

Comment: Martin Industries went bankrupt and was liquidated in 2003. There are some Martin manuals on [ManualsOnline.com](http://homeappliance.manualsonline.com/manuals/mfg/martin/martin_indoor_fireplace_product_list.html), but none for the 5500. You might get some help searching the other models' manuals.

Comment: Looks pretty dirty down there. Clean it out. When no spark, I find the problem is *usually* a dirty ignition point or plug. -clean with sandpaper or brush. Also abrade the area to which to spark is supposed to fire. Dirty spider webs in the spark path may be your only problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have one of these fireplaces. The glass front does come off. If I recall correctly remove the piece above the glass front first and then you'll see retaining clips holding the glass front in place.